PyQt6, как сделать QTextEdit полностью раскрытым в QVBoxLayout?
Всем привет, помогите, пожалуйста с PyQt6! Заранее спасибо.
У меня есть некий обьект layout = QVBoxLayout(). Он также находится в QScrollArea, так что при переполнении может прокручиваться.
Затем, по вызову функции в него добавляются QTextEdit.
Проблема в том, что когда в любом из QTextEdit контента мало, он все равно слишком длинный, просто так отображается много лишних строк. Когда строк в нем слишком много, у него появляется скроллбар, а размер не меняется. Подскажите, как сделать автоподбор размера по высоте для него?

somokill , пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему
